# How to get the name of original file while merging with renames in git?

Tags: git, conflict, git-merge, file-rename

When git performs merge with a proper `renameLimit` setting, it tries to find renames among all changed files. And if git finds one with conflicts, then it puts the line in a `git status`:

> both modified:      src/new_file_name.cc

Where `new_file_name.cc` is a resulting name of the renamed file, as I suggest.

But how to find an original name of this file? And how to find out if it's a renaming at first?

Comment: Does `git diff --cached --stat` show files which got removed? Maybe your file is among those.